# How to delete an item from a table which affect another table in laravel 5.4?

Tags: database, relationship, laravel-5.4

I have the following tables:

```
{
    Schema::create('properties', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('property_name');
        $table->integer('category_id');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

and

```
{
    Schema::create('categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

I registered a property with a category ID. After that, I delete a category in the table category and I get the following message:

```
(1/2) ErrorException
Trying to get property of non-object

Trying to get property of non-object (View: C:\laragon\www\PRO\resources\views\properties\index.blade.php)
```

The message comes up when I try to see the properties because of the **category ID** which was connected to them is not there anymore.

## **How to fix this error please?** Thank you in advance!!!

After the suggested code insertion I got the following error message:

```
(1/1) FatalThrowableError
Class 'App\CategoryDeleted' not found
in HasEvents.php (line 165)
at Model->fireCustomModelEvent('deleted', 'fire')
in HasEvents.php (line 140)
at Model->fireModelEvent('deleted', false)
in Model.php (line 754)
at Model->delete()
in CategoryController.php (line 114)
at CategoryController->destroy('3')
at call_user_func_array(array(object(CategoryController), 'destroy'), array('category' => '3'))
in Controller.php (line 55)
at Controller->callAction('destroy', array('category' => '3'))
in ControllerDispatcher.php (line 44)
at ControllerDispatcher->dispatch(object(Route), object(CategoryController), 'destroy')
in Route.php (line 203)
```

> This is my category controller:

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Property;
use App\Category;
use Session;
use App\Events\CategoryDeleted;

class CategoryController extends Controller
{
     public function __construct()

    {

    $this->middleware(['auth', 'admin']);

    }
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
       //indexing the categories from the database
        $categories = Category::orderBy('id', 'desc')->paginate(100000);
        //return a view and pass the above variable
        return view('categories.index')->withCategories($categories);
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        //Showing the registratin form for the cities
        return view('categories.create');
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
         //Seve a new category
        $this->validate($request, array(
            'name' => 'unique:categories|max:255'
            ));
        $category = new Category;
        $category->name = $request->name;
        $category->save();
        Session::flash('success', 'A new Category has been successfully saved!');
        return redirect()->route('categories.index');
    }

    /**
     * 
    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit($id)
    {
        // find the category in the database and save as a var
        $category = Category::find($id);
       // return the view and pass in the var we previously created
        return view('categories.edit')->withCategory($category);
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $category = Category::find($id);
        // Validate the data
          $this->validate($request, array(
            'name' => 'unique:categories|max:255'
            ));

         $category = Category::find($id);
         $category->name = $request->input('name');

        // Save the data to the database
         $category->save();

          Session::flash('success', 'A new Category has been successfully updated!');
        // redirect with flash data to cities index
         return redirect()->route('categories.index');
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy($id)
    {
        $category = Category::find($id);
        $category->delete();
      Session::flash('success', 'The category was successfully deleted.');
      return redirect()->route('categories.index');
    }
}
```

This is the suggested code:
[https://stackoverflow.com/a/45190713/7705605](http://stackoverflow.com/a/45190713/7705605)

Bear in mind the table name is properties instead for products and I have made the changes in the suggested code. I mean change the word products for properties. Thank you again!

> This is my event is placed in app\events, is named CategoryDeleted.php
>   and look like this:

```
<?php

namespace App\Events;

use App\Category;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;

/**
 * Class CategoryDeleted
 * @package App\Events
 */
class CategoryDeleted
{
    use SerializesModels;

    /**
     * @var Category
     */
    public $category;

    /**
     * Create a new event instance.
     *
     * @param Category $category
     */
    public function __construct(Category $category)
    {
        $this->category = $category;
    }
}
```

> This is my listener placed in Listeners and named
>   DissociatePropertiesFromDeletedCategory.php:

```
    namespace App\Listeners;

    use App\Events\CategoryDeleted;
    // use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
    // use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;

    class DissociatePropertiesFromDeletedCategory
    {
        /**
         * Create the event listener.
         *
         * @return void
         */
        public function __construct()
        {
            //
        }

        /**
         * Handle the event.
         *
         * @param  CategoryDeleted  $event
         * @return void
         */
        public function handle(CategoryDeleted $event)
        {
             $event->category->properties()->update(['category_id' => null]);
        }
    }
```

> This is EventServiceProvider.php:

```
 <?php

    namespace App\Providers;

    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Event;
    use Illuminate\Foundation\Support\Providers\EventServiceProvider as ServiceProvider;

    class EventServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
    {
        /**
         * The event listener mappings for the application.
         *
         * @var array
         */
        protected $listen = [
            'App\Events\RegistrationCompleted' => [
                'App\Listeners\SendRegistrationEmail',

           ],

            'App\Events\CategoryDeleted' => [
            'App\Listeners\DissociatePropertiesFromDeletedCategory',
        ],

            ];

        /**
         * Register any events for your application.
         *
         * @return void
         */
        public function boot()
        {
            parent::boot();

            //
        }
    }
```

> This is my Category Model:

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Category extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'categories';

    public function properties ()

    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Property');
    }

    protected $events = [
    'deleted' => CategoryDeleted::class,
];

}
```

> This is my Property Model:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Property extends Model
{
     //Category
    public function category ()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Category');
    }

    //City
    public function city ()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\City');
    }

    //Country
    public function country ()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Country');
    }

    //Tag
    public function tags()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Tag');
    }

    //Appraiser

     //Tag
    public function appraiser()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Appraiser');
    }
}
```

> This is may propertyController:

```
   <?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Property;
use Session;
use App\City;
use App\Country;
use App\Category;
use App\Appraiser;


class PropertyController extends Controller
{

    public function __construct()

    {
    $this->middleware(['auth', 'admin']);
    }
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
       //create and index the properties from the database
        $properties = Property::orderBy('id', 'desc')->paginate(100000);
        //return a view and pass the above variable
        return view('properties.index')->withProperties($properties);
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        //Call all categories/cities/coutries/tags and everything else to show them in the form
        $categories      = Category::all();
        $cities          = City::all();
        $countries       = Country::all();
        $appraisers      = Appraiser::all();       
        // $tags = Tag::all();
        return view('properties.create')->withCategories($categories)->withCities($cities)->withCountries($countries)->withAppraisers($appraisers);
        // ->withTags($tags);
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
         // dd($request);
         $this->validate($request, [

                //Location
            'address'         => 'required|max:255',
            'city_id'         => 'required|integer',
            'country_id'      => 'required|integer',
            'category_id'     => 'required|integer',
            'website'         => 'nullable|url',
            'slug'            => 'required|alpha_dash|min:5|max:155|unique:properties,slug',
                // 'image'           =>'nullable|image',
            'comment'         => 'nullable|max:255',

                //Financial
            'price_paid'        => 'required|integer',
            'loan_ltv'          => 'required|integer',
            'rent'              => 'required|integer',
            'mortgage'          => 'required|integer',
            'management_moe'    => 'required|integer',
            'o_fees'            => 'required|integer',
            'contingencies'     => 'nullable|integer',
            'diligence'         => 'nullable|integer',
            'letting_agent_fees'=> 'nullable|integer',

            //Contact

            'appraiser_id'      => 'nullable|integer',
            ]);

        //store in the database
        $property = new Property;
        //Location
        $property->address               = $request->address;
        $property->city_id               = $request->city_id;
        $property->country_id            = $request->country_id;
        $property->category_id           = $request->category_id;
        $property->website               = $request->website;
        $property->slug                  = $request->slug;
        // $property->image                 =$request->image;
        $property->comment              = $request->comment;
        //Financial
        $property->price_paid           = $request->price_paid;
        $property->loan_ltv             = $request->loan_ltv;
        $property->rent                 = $request->rent;
        $property->mortgage             = $request->mortgage;
        $property->management_moe       = $request->management_moe;
        $property->o_fees               = $request->o_fees;
        $property->contingencies        = $request->contingencies;
        $property->diligence            = $request->diligence;
        $property->letting_agent_fees   = $request->letting_agent_fees;
        //Contacts
        $property->appraiser_id         = $request->appraiser_id;
        //store in the database
        $property->save();

        // $property->tags()->sync($request->tags, false);

        //Flash session informing the data was successfully save
        Session::flash('success', 'The property project was successfully saved!');
        //redirect to the page you want
        return redirect()->route('properties.show', $property->id);
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show(Property $property)
    {
       return view('properties.show')->withProperty($property);
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
   public function edit(Property $property)

    {


         //Category
        $categories = Category::all();
        $cats = array();
        foreach ($categories as $category) {
            $cats[$category->id] = $category->name;
        }

        //City

        $cities = City::all();
        $home = array();
        foreach ($cities as $city) {
            $home[$city->id] = $city->name;
        }
        //Country
        $countries = Country::all();
        $place = array();
        foreach ($countries as $country) {
            $place[$country->id] = $country->name;
        }

        //Appraiser
         $appraisers = Appraiser::all();
        $apprai = array();
        foreach ($appraisers as $appraiser) {
            $apprai[$appraiser->id] = $appraiser->first_name;
        }

        // $tags = Tag::all();
        return view('properties.edit')->withProperty($property)->withCategories($cats)->withCities($home)->withCountries($place)->withAppraisers($apprai);
        // ->withTags($tags);
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $property = Property::find($id);

       if ($request->input('slug')== $property->slug) {
            $this->validate($request, array(

                 //Location
            'address'         => 'required|max:255',
            'city_id'         => 'required|integer',
            'country_id'      => 'required|integer',
            'category_id'     => 'required|integer',
            'website'         => 'nullable|url',
            // 'slug'            => 'required|alpha_dash|min:5|max:155|unique:properties,slug',
                // 'image'           =>'nullable|image',
            'comment'         => 'nullable|max:255',

                //Financial
            'price_paid'        => 'required|integer',
            'loan_ltv'          => 'required|integer',
            'rent'              => 'required|integer',
            'mortgage'          => 'required|integer',
            'management_moe'    => 'required|integer',
            'o_fees'            => 'required|integer',
            'contingencies'     => 'nullable|integer',
            'diligence'         => 'nullable|integer',
            'letting_agent_fees'=> 'nullable|integer',

            //Contact

            'appraiser_id'      => 'nullable|integer',

                ));

        } else {

            $this->validate($request, array(

                //Location
            'address'         => 'required|max:255',
            'city_id'         => 'required|integer',
            'country_id'      => 'required|integer',
            'category_id'     => 'required|integer',
            'website'         => 'nullable|url',
            'slug'            => 'required|alpha_dash|min:5|max:155|unique:properties,slug',
                // 'image'           =>'nullable|image',
            'comment'         => 'nullable|max:255',

                //Financial
            'price_paid'        => 'required|integer',
            'loan_ltv'          => 'required|integer',
            'rent'              => 'required|integer',
            'mortgage'          => 'required|integer',
            'management_moe'    => 'required|integer',
            'o_fees'            => 'required|integer',
            'contingencies'     => 'nullable|integer',
            'diligence'         => 'nullable|integer',
            'letting_agent_fees'=> 'nullable|integer',

            //Contact

            'appraiser_id'      => 'nullable|integer',

                ));
        }

        //store in the database


        $property->address               = $request->input('address');
        $property->city_id               = $request->input('city_id');
        $property->country_id            = $request->input('country_id');
        $property->category_id           = $request->input('category_id');
        $property->website               = $request->input('website');
        $property->slug                  = $request->input('slug');
        // $property->image                 =$request->input('image');
        $property->comment              = $request->input('comment');
        //Financial
        $property->price_paid           = $request->input('price_paid');
        $property->loan_ltv             = $request->input('loan_ltv');
        $property->rent                 = $request->input('rent');
        $property->mortgage             = $request->input('mortgage');
        $property->management_moe       = $request->input('management_moe');
        $property->o_fees               = $request->input('o_fees');
        $property->contingencies        = $request->input('contingencies');
        $property->diligence            = $request->input('diligence');
        $property->letting_agent_fees   = $request->input('letting_agent_fees');

        $property->category_id          =$request->input('category_id');
        $property->city_id              =$request->input('city_id');
        $property->country_id           =$request->input('country_id');
         $property->appraiser_id        =$request->input('appraiser_id');

        $property->save();

         Session::flash('success', 'The property project was successfully updated!');

          return redirect()->route('properties.show', $property->id);
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy($id)
    {   
        $property = Property::find($id);
        // $pos->tags()->detach();
         $property->category()->detach();
         $property->city()->detach();
         $property->country()->detach();
        $property->delete();
        Session::flash('success', 'The project was successfully deleted.');
        return redirect()->route('properties.index');
    }
}
```

> This is my index.blade.php:

```
   @section('content')










    </section>

    <!-- Main content -->
    <section class="content">
    @include('layouts.admin-partials.messages')
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12">


                <div class="box">
                    <div class="box-header">
                        <h3 class="box-title">Data Table With Full Features</h3>
                    </div>
                    <!-- /.box-header -->
                    <div class="box-body">
                        <table id="example1" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
                            <thead>
                              <tr>
                               <th>#</th>
                               <th>Address</th>
                               <th>City</th>
                               <th>Country</th>
                               <th>Category</th>
                               <th>Price</th>
                               <th>Loan</th>
                               <th>Rent</th>
                               <th>Mortgage</th>
                               <th>Manage</th>
                               <th>Other Fees.</th>
                               <th>Contingencies</th> 
                               <th>Diligencies</th>
                               <th> View</th>


                           </tr>
                       </thead>
                       <tbody>
                        @foreach ($properties as $property)

                        <tr>
                            <td>{{ $property->id }}</td>
                            <td>
                                <a>{{ $property->address }}</a>
                                <br />
                                <small>{{ date('M j, Y h:ia', strtotime($property->created_at)) }}</small>
                            </td>
                            <td>{{ $property->city->name }} </td>
                            <td> {{ $property->country->name }}</td>
                            <td> {{ $property->category->name }}</td>
                            <td> {{ $property->price_paid }}</td>
                            <td> {{ $property->loan_ltv }}</td>
                            <td> {{ $property->rent }}</td>
                            <td> {{ $property->mortgage }}</td>
                            <td> {{ $property->management_moe }}</td>
                            <td> {{ $property->o_fees}}</td>
                            <td> {{ $property->contingencies}}</td>
                            <td> {{ $property->diligence}}</td>



                            <td>
                                <a href="{{ route('properties.show', $property->id) }}" class="btn btn-success btn-xs"><i class="fa fa-folder"></i> View </a>
                                <a href="{{ route('properties.edit', $property->id) }}" class="btn btn-info btn-xs"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i> Edit </a>
                                <!-- Button trigger modal -->
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash" aria-hidden="true"></span>&nbsp;Delete</span>
                              </button>

                              <!-- Modal -->
                              <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
                                  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                                    <div class="modal-content">
                                      <div class="modal-header">
                                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                                        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Delete?</h4>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="modal-body">
                                        Do you really want to delete this project?
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="modal-footer">
                                    <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-xs-3">
                                      <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                                      </div>
                                      <div class="col-xs-3 col-md-offset-4">
                                     {!! Form::open(['route' => ['properties.destroy', $property->id], 'method' => 'DELETE']) !!}
                                     {!! Form::submit('Delete', ['class' => 'btn btn-success btn-md']) !!}

                                    {!! Form::close() !!}
                                    </div>
                                    </div>
                                 </div>
                             </div>
                         </div>
                     </div>
                     <!-- /Button trigger modal -->
                 </td>

             </tr>

             @endforeach 
         </tbody>
         <tfoot>
           <tr>
               <th>#</th>
               <th>Address</th>
               <th>City</th>
               <th>Country</th>
               <th>Category</th>
               <th>Price</th>
               <th>Loan</th>
               <th>Rent</th>
               <th>Mortgage</th>
               <th>Manage</th>
               <th>Other Fees.</th>
               <th>Contingencies</th> 
               <th>Diligencies</th>
               <th> View</th>


           </tr>
       </tfoot>
   </table>
</div>
<!-- /.box-body -->
</div>
<!-- /.box -->
</div>
<!-- /.col -->
</div>
<!-- /.row -->
</section>
<!-- /.content -->
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to update the process of your system to avoid that kind of error.

You need to add an eloquent event on your Category model that will free all products connected to it, making them with no category anymore.

Using Laravel 5.4, try this:

1. Create new event.

   ```
   <?php

   namespace App\Events;

   use App\Category;
   use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;

   /**
    * Class CategoryDeleted
    * @package App\Events
    */
   class CategoryDeleted
   {
       use SerializesModels;

       /**
        * @var Category
        */
       public $category;

       /**
        * Create a new event instance.
        *
        * @param Category $category
        */
       public function __construct(Category $category)
       {
           $this->category = $category;
       }
   }
   ```
2. Create listener to your event.

   ```
   <?php

   namespace App\Listeners;

   use App\Events\CategoryDeleted;

   /**
    * Class DissociatePropertiesFromDeletedCategory
    * @package App\Listeners
    */
   class DissociatePropertiesFromDeletedCategory
   {
       /**
        * Handle the event.
        *
        * @param  CategoryDeleted $event
        * @return void
        */
       public function handle(CategoryDeleted $event)
       {
           $event->category->properties()->update(['category_id' => null]);
       }
   }
   ```
3. Add the following on your `App\Category` model class:

   ```
   /**
    * @var array
    */
   protected $events = [
       'deleted' => CategoryDeleted::class,
   ];
   ```
4. Set the event/listener in your event service provider:

   ```
   /**
    * The event listener mappings for the application.
    *
    * @var array
    */
   protected $listen = [
       'App\Events\CategoryDeleted' => [
           'App\Listeners\DissociatePropertiesFromDeletedCategory',
       ],
   ];
   ```
5. You have to make sure that `account_id` field in your properties table is nullable.
6. Lastly, make sure you already have the relationship set on category model.

   ```
   /**
    * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany
    */
   public function properties()
   {
       return $this->hasMany('App\Properties');
   }
   ```

For more information, see laravel eloquent event docs [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent#events).

Comment: @AlexeiMartinez i just updated my answer with the step-by-step instructions. let me know if it works ;)

Comment: If I have to update different Models, do I have to do the same process for all the Models?

Comment: @AlexeiMartinez: You edited this answer instead of editing your question and/or comment this answer. Your edit will be rejected.

Comment: @AlexeiMartinez yes i meant model category. you can use property model instead of product, the logic is same.

regarding the new error, you have to make sure that your `CategoryDeleleted` class namespace is `App\Events`

Comment: @AlexeiMartinez I think you've missed to modify your Category model in your edited question above. Also make sure you apply step #6

Comment: ahh, you missed to import `CategoryDeleted` class in your Category model `use App\Events\CategoryDeleted;`

Comment: Update: Hello, elegisandi! I tested the code and deleted a category again. When I return to see properties.index I got the same error **Trying to get property of non-object**. I check the table categories and of course, the deleted category is gone. The event ran smoothly but the error still remains :-(. Any other suggestion? Thanks a ton!

Comment: @AlexeiMartinez in your blade file, you have to check first if a property has a category assigned. eg `$property->category ? $property->category->id : 0`. do whats applicable to your system.

Comment: Hello, elegisandi! My blade has  `$property->Category->name }}`, since the user would want to see the name in the table view instead. I have attached the index.blade above. Should I see check another blade, place?

Comment: I was thinking if the index.blade needs some php logic? Because the function works as expected and I get null in the DB.  :-)

Comment: @Alexie in your blade, you need to check if property has category so that it won't throw an error. Use this `$property->category ? $property->category->name : ''`. Or you can use whatever to represent that it has no category.

Comment: Yuppy!!! The system is working now thank a ton for your help!!  I don't know if the rest of the user see your comments but it would be great if it is so!

Comment: glad to help :) please don't forget to set the question to answered and also upvote will be appreciated ;)

Comment: Hello there elegisandi?  I have tried to close the question and vote but I don't know if I did well. I hope so! The code work perfect thanks again for the help! I have however 20 models to update and I wonder if there is a way to do this to all the models.

Comment: I did.`'App\Events\ContactDeleted' => [
        'App\Listeners\DissociatePropertiesFromDeletedAppraiser',
        'App\Listeners\DissociatePropertiesFromDeletedBanker',
        'App\Listeners\DissociatePropertiesFromDeletedBroker',
        'App\Listeners\DissociatePropertiesFromDeletedCompany', ],` but I got **error**Cannot redeclare class. Any Idea?

Comment: you might have missed to modify the classname of one of your listeners (common copy & paste flaw)